# How can solve: too many values to unpack

Tags: api

I need get all the information of this public API, but I have the error 'too many values to unpack' in the second code. I think we can get all the information of 30 million of people in Peru. I don't know if the code is correct. I'm a beginner.

```
import requests
```

```
parameter= {"72212376"}
request = requests.get('https://api.reniec.cloud/dni/',parameter)
```

```
DNI_json = request.json()
for i in DNI_json[0:300000]:
 print(i['dni'])
```